# How to make login and signup in one url

Tags: python, html, django

Im new in Django. Got a problem. I have my urls.py:

```
    path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    path('reset/', auth_views.password_reset, name='reset'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

So i can login using one HTML file and signup using other.
But i have a HTML including and login and signup. The problem is that if i use /login/ url i can only log in and if i try the same forms to sign up - it does not work. The same with signup (only signup).
How can i make both that functions work using one url and one HTML file.
Thanks!
Here is HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
      <form class="register-form" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя" required autofocus id="id_username"
             maxlength="150"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required id="id_email" maxlength="200" />
                <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="пароль" required id="id_password1"/>
                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="повторите пароль" required id="id_password2"/>
      <button type="submit">создать</button>
      <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#">Войти.</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя"  for=<input type="text" name="username"
             maxlength="254" autofocus required id="id_username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="пароль" for=<input type="password" name="password"
           id="id_password" required />
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
      <button type="submit">войти</button>
      <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: <form class="register-form" method="POST"> action missing

Comment: Do you change the action attribute before sending your form ?

Comment: Hey guys! It works. I forgot that action. Sorry for so stupid question, just spent a lot of time for that.